# InStr() functionality

Tags: autohotkey

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how the AutoHotKey function works.  Here's some test code:

```
pos = InStr(123abc789, abc)
MsgBox, abc is at pos "%pos%"
Exit
```

The MsgBox reads:

> abc is at pos "InStr(123abc789, abc)"

I'm expecting the value of pos to be 4.

Now, the AutoHotKey help file states about `InStr()`:

```
InStr(Haystack, Needle [, CaseSensitive = false, StartingPos = 1, Occurrence = 1]):
```

Returns the position of an occurrence of the string Needle in the string Haystack... For example, the position of "abc" in "123abc789" is always 4.

What's up??

Answer (score 2):

You are missing 2 things.  You must make sure to use the `:=` assignment and also to put the strings in quotes.  See the modified code below:

```
pos := InStr("123abc789", "abc") ; strings must be in quotes unless variables
MsgBox, abc is at pos "%pos%"
```

Answer (score -1):

Also:

```
MsgBox, abc is at pos "%pos%"
```

can not work, variables are required to be between percentage signs, no quotes.

This will work:

```
MsgBox, abc is at pos %pos%
```

Comment: This is wrong.  The quotes will be printed: 
abc is at pos "%pos%" 
will result in 
abc is at pos "4"